# Using javascript/google places to load in reviews dynamically into review schema (for rich snippets)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-crawlers, rich-snippets

The first time i hardcoded the reviews of my company into the page it got indexed in a single day (for the review rich snippet) by using this code:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "CreativeWorkSeries",
    "name": "Review",
    "aggregateRating":{
      "ratingValue": "0",
      "bestRating": "10",
      "worstRating": "1",
      "ratingCount": "0"
    }
  }
</script>
```

I made a script that basically loads in the reviews of 2 locations of my company. When i inspect my page in the dev tools elements, it looks like everythings working fine, the numbers and rating are both loaded in correctly but there is no result in google search results. This is the full code i use to load in the data:

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
  let places = ['placeid1', 'placeid2']
  var totalReviews = 0;
  var totalRating = 0;
  let numberOfPlaces = 0;
  getRecensies()


 async function getRecensies(){
      let counter = 0;
      await new Promise(function(resolve) {
           places.forEach((place)=>{
              service.getDetails({
                  placeId: place,
              },function(result, status) {
                  console.log("result", result)

                  if(result && result.rating && result.user_ratings_total){
                      totalRating = totalRating + result.rating;
                      totalReviews = totalReviews + result.user_ratings_total;
                      numberOfPlaces++
                  }
                  counter++
                  if(counter==places.length){
                      resolve()
                  }
                  
              });
          })
      })

      //totalRating = (totalRating / numberOfPlaces); // Get average rating

      var schemaElement = document.getElementById('review-schema-home');
      var schema = JSON.parse(schemaElement.textContent); 
      schema.aggregateRating.ratingValue = totalRating.toString();
      schema.aggregateRating.ratingCount = totalReviews.toString();
      schemaElement.textContent = JSON.stringify(schema, null, 2);

     }
      
  });
  </script>

<script type="application/ld+json" id="review-schema-home">
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "CreativeWorkSeries",
    "name": "Review",
    "aggregateRating":{
      "ratingValue": "0",
      "bestRating": "10",
      "worstRating": "1",
      "ratingCount": "0"
    }
  }
</script>
```

this next screenshot is from my inspector, as you can see the data loads in correctly.
I made the script in the first place so i did not have to update my review amount manually. It looks like i'm gonna have to hard code this weekly.

Im curious if google spiders can crawl and execute scripts like this? Or another explanation why the review snippet is not appearing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First off, while the Google crawler [can read JavaScript](https://ipullrank.com/javascript-seo-how-google-crawls-and-indexes-javascript-websites) and can also wait "a bit" till the on-page JS loads, I wouldn't rely on the script you've shown above.

There's no guarantee that `getRecensies` will resolve by the time the Googlebot has finished parsing your page.

On top of that, your script will run **on each page load** which may affect your Google Cloud bill. Also, if your API key you've used to load the API onto your page isn't protected, bad actors may misuse it to run their own Places API queries!

Overall, not a good idea.

---

Now, from Google's own [troubleshooting website](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/review-snippet#troubleshooting):

> Google **does not guarantee** that features that consume structured data will show up in search results. For a list of common reasons why Google may not show your content in a rich result, see the [General Structured Data Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/sd-policies).

Hard-coding and regularly updating the review snippets is perfectly fine – as long as the markup is properly structured. You can test your markup with [these two tools](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data).

Once your markup has been consumed by the Googlebot, you'll see something like this in [GSC](https://search.google.com/search-console/about):
[image]

But, AFAIK, this still **does not guarantee** that the enhancements will be present in the SERPs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joe. This was not really what i meant though. 

Hardcoded, it works perfectly fine (and the snippet is visible in the search engine). I wanted the snippet to load in data dynamically from the maps api by using the javascript i wrote. Which works when i check the code in the inspector but doesnt show the snippet in the search engine.

my guess is that its updated to frequently for google to validate it.

Comment: Oh I see. I assume that your script is taking "a bit too long" to run in order for google to index the results properly. Can you debug/time this function's execution? One more option: don't fill `review-schema-home` with the hard-coded JSON. Leave it empty and let your script populate it. Google might assume you're trying to do womething fishy by replacing the schema content... Again, just assumptions here.

Comment: Good suggestion thanks, i will look that up. I really cant be the execution time. i made sure its one of the first scripts that run on this page.